# LocalStack API Gateway "OperationNotFoundParseError" Unable to find operation for request to service apigateway

Tags: localstack

I've been really struggling with API Gateway on localstack :( I have managed to deploy a very simple CDK project that creates an API Gateway that just proxies requests.  This works on "actual" AWS but not localstack.

I try to do a GET on my API Gateway endpoint using the URL pattern described where local DNS issues prevent the default URL from working [LocalStack API Gateway docs](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/aws/apigateway/) e.g. `http://localhost:4566/restapis/0v1p6q6/local/_user_request_/my/path1` but this didn't work at all for me - encountering the problem described here [No Such Bucket](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/5418)

This seems odd - a GET using Curl or a browser just doesn't work, so maybe I have gone wrong before this point.  Localstack is running in docker btw.

Using the solution at the end of the [discussion](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/5418) which is to add a special header, I am able to make the request but it then fails with the message:

`Unknown Operation: unable to find operation for request to service apigateway.`  The bit where the exception is raised in the localstack source code is [here](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/blob/2977f13b8028bcc8b393e9797a2ac37f78e9b590/localstack/aws/protocol/parser.py#LL559C4-L559C4)

Any help or pointers much appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

I missed an _ from the end of the URL nightmare !

[Github issue](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/8294)